# How can I undo my last git add/commit?

Tags: git, repository, commit, undo

I edited a file and did:

```
git add file.py
git commit -m 'fixed bug'
```

I then edited another file and performed a minor bug fix. I don't want two commits, one after the other, showing 'bug fix'. I want one commit with 'bug fixes'.

How can I undo the last add/commit and change the first commit message?

I was looking at the `git reset`, `git revert`, `git undo` commands but I don't want to screw up my repo with a guess

EDIT: Found out how to do it: http://www.gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

Answer (score 48):

If you already commited your second change, reset it first:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

Now your `HEAD` is at the first commit, and the content of your local files is unchanged.

```
git add <the file(s) for the second bug fix>
git commit --amend -m'bug fixes'
```

If all tracked and changed file are to be included for the second bug fix, you can run this instead, as usual:

```
git commit -a --amend
```

Amending the commit is exactly this:

- adds the changes in index to the previous commit (therefore the need for `git add`, or `-a`)
- allows you to change your commit message

Be careful, though: if you have distributed the first commit, other people's repo will get strange. You should not change a commit that someone else has fetched.

---

You could also probably use `git merge --squash`, which feels more logical but not necessarily easier. Use it to merge a branch containing your two commits, unto the previous commit.

Squashing works with `git rebase` as well.

Comment: With the two I files I edited, I already did `git add file; git commit`. Doing `git --amend -m 'asd'` would just edit my previous commit message, wouldn't it? Leaving the first commit in the log?

Comment: No, `--amend` adds the content of the index to the newly created commit. The old commit disappears (becomes dangling). Chances are that you can still see it in gitk, run a reload (Ctrl+F5) in gitk to make it disappear. The dangling commit will disappear from memory later on (`git gc` should clean it out).

Comment: did you commit twice already? In that case you can precede the commands above with `git reset HEAD^`. Please backup your repo before doing all this (make sure the folder .git is in your backup), I don't want to be responsible of data loss.

Comment: I don't have anything in the index. I have two commits that I want to merge into one...